# Flashing ! icon in Strike playlist on Destiny

Tags: destiny

In destiny on the strike playlist one of the items is flashing with a ! on it - now normally ! is a quest/storyline item but I don't see why this would show up in the strike playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Destiny uses the flashing exclamation icon to indicate any new activity that is available.

Primarily this is story/quest items as you note but it also appears when you unlock new playlists for Strikes , Crucible and access to Raids all things which can happen as you continue to increase the light level of your characters.

Likely the recent it recently showed up on the Strike playlist is that the Dark Below expansion added a new Level 26 Strike playlist so provided you are sufficiently levelled it would be a new activity for you to participate in.  Note however that this playlist does require you to own the Dark Below expansion